# Calculating breadth first traversal correctly?

Tags: breadth-first-search

I was wondering if I am correctly calculating breadth first traversal based on a graph.

[image]

Based on this, I figured it would be traversed as A, B, C, E, F, D as I am going across each row before moving on. Is this the correct way of thinking?

Comment: That is correct... Visit all children of a parent first before moving onto the next. Better yet, take it this way, you visit A and add all its children to a queue. So, that'll be B,C,E.  Now visit the next element in the queue and add its children. So now the queue looks C,E,F. And the rest follows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct because
the part that you might be confused about could be when does the BFS return a node in the path. It's mostly when we pop the left element of the queue.
lets try to visualize queue :

```
[A]
-> pops and prints A after adding A's immediate neighbours to the queue
[B,C,E] 
[C,E,F]
[E,F,D]
[F,D]
[D]
[]
```